# Rewrite $\sum_{n=1}^k{(n-1)/n!}$ and write the formula in terms of k

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, telescopic-series

Rewrite $\sum_{n=1}^k{\frac{n-1}{n!}}$

I have turned it into $\frac{1}{n}*\frac{1}{(n-2)!}$ but do not know where to go from here.

Comment: This looks like a fun problem.  Is there some part of it that you are stuck on?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: The funny thing is, that you´ve already tagged your question with `telescopic series` from the beginning :)

Comment: If you don´t have any further questions please mark one answer as accepted ($\color{limegreen}{\checkmark}$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^k{\frac{n-1}{n!}} = \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{(n-1)!} - \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n!}.
$$

Comment: Thank you! I rewrote it using the method you suggested and got $\frac{1}{0!}-\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{1!}-\frac{1}{2!}...$ and ended with $\frac{1}{k!}+\frac{1}{0!}$ or $\frac{1}{k!}+1$

Answer (score 4):

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^k(f(n-1)-f(n))$$

$$=f(0)-f(k)$$ where $f(n)=\dfrac1{n!}$

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series